# Jquery each wait for modal to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, modal-dialog, each

I am trying to show modal dialogs in a `$.each()` loop and in each iteration I'm dynamically changing the data of the modal.

```
$.each(real_names, function (key, value) {
      $('#restore-modal').find('.asset_name').text(value.relative_name);
      $('#restore-modal').modal('open');
}
```

The problem is `$.each()` is not waiting for the user to interact with the modal or the modal to get closed.

How can I wait for the user to interact with the modal or the modal to get closed?

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly but you want a loop to hold and wait until the modal it opened is closed and then loop around again to open the next instance of the modal? If that is so, I wouldn't "pause" a loop but use events instead. Trigger an event on modal closed instead, to signify the next modal can be opened or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the API of the modal library you use, but you could probably try with a **recursive function**, with its counter, it would permit you to loop over the `real_names` array while giving you full control of the loop:

```
var counter = 0;

function openModal() {
  // first a mecanism to escape the recursion:
  if (counter === real_names.length) {
    return;
  }

  // not sure about your code here, but for the idea:
  $('#restore-modal').find('.asset_name').text(real_names[counter].relative_name);
  $('#restore-modal').modal('open');

  // here, depending on how your modal API works, you can call again 
  // the openModal function after the desired event (user closing modal,
  // clicking on confirmation...),
  // first incrementing the counter for searching the next modal

  // or make the function return, to escape the recursion for any other event
}
```